# Sequelize.js - model association during "create" or "build" call

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a data model where an association/foreign key is required. Is there any way possible to enforce that constraint during model creation without getting into a chicken/egg situation?

Let's say I have a `User` class which requires at least one `device` to be associated with it. Likewise, the `device` must belong to a user. Something like this (untested code, don't mind syntax errors):

```
User = db.define("user", {
    name: Sequelize.STRING
})

Device = db.define("device", {
    uuid: Sequelize.STRING
})

User.hasMany(Device)
```

I want to ensure that when `create` is first called, that I have all `Device` information as well as all `User` information. Keeping with "fat models, skinny controllers" I'd like to put this into my models. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
user = User.create(
    name: "jesse"
    device:
        uuid: "84e824cb-bfae-4d95-a76d-51103c556057"
)
```

Can I override the `create` method? Or is there some type of `before` save event hook I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current master has support for hooks.

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
  username: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
  hooks: {
    beforeCreate: function(user, next) {
      makeYourCheck(function() {
        next("a string means that an error happened.")
      })
    }
  }
})
```

You can check the PR for further information: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/894